# Jquery animate isn't animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm working on a web site that uses the jquery animate function to expand the web site from the top left corner when it is loaded. I wasn't actually the one who wrote the code for that feature so I'm not overly familiar with it. It did work at one point but at the moment it doesn't seem to be working at all. I know the .js file is being loaded and is running because the first bit of code in it is a time delay that shows a "Page is being loaded" message. But then it just shows the page already loaded instead of animating the page appearing from the top left and sliding in. I included the CSS and mark up also although I don't believe that's where the problem lies. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

*Note: We're using Jquery version 1.7.2*

The CSS:

```
 #builder
    {
        position:relative;
        min-height:100%;
        min-width:100%;
        z-index:999;
    }
```

The JavaScript:

```
function hideIt() {

    document.getElementById("wait").style.display = "none";

}

setTimeout("hideIt()", 1000);

function showIt() {

    document.getElementById("builder").style.display = "block";
}

setTimeout("showIt()", 2500);

function build() {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#builder").animate({ height: '0%', width: '0%' }, 1);
        $("#builder").animate({ height: '100%', width: '100%' }, 2000);


    });
}
```

The mark up:

```
<body onLoad="build()">
<img src="wait.gif" id="wait" style="display:block;" />
```

wait.gif is just a picture that says "page is loading"...

And the page is wrapped in these:

```
<div id="builder" align=center style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the #builder element is hidden for 2.5 seconds before it's shown, the animation will be completed by the time the element is shown. Remove the inline function on body onLoad and try:

```
function hideIt() {
    $("#wait").hide();
}

function showIt() {
    $("#builder").show(2000); //should do somewhat the same as animating from the top left
}

$(function() {
    setTimeout(hideIt, 1000); //no need to quote the functions and eval them
    setTimeout(showIt, 2500);
});
```

or just

```
$("#wait").delay(1000).hide(10);
$("#builder").delay(2500).show(2000)
```

Comment: This is actually almost exactly what they want it to do, however it is only animating the background image and not all of the content on the page...

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by the content not being animated, is the content within the #builder element, otherwise it will of course not be animated, or is it just not animated the way you'd like it to be ?

Comment: I think that's more than likely the problem, some of the markup probably needs to be changed, I'll have to look at it tomorrow as I'm done with work for the night already, thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your code like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wait').hide(1000, function(){  // hide the #wait
        $("#builder").show().animate({ // then show, then animate #builder
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%'
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

**Side Note:** Remember that when you're using percentages and the element containing `#builder`, also needs to have it's height and width set.

Comment: I tried it but with that javascript it never got past the page is loading message...

Comment: I made an edit in the code. Also, given you now call `build()` when the document is good and loaded, you can remove the onLoad attribute from your body tag. AND: the animation happens long before `#builder` gets shown. I presume you want it to animate to it's full size during it's first appearance?

Comment: Okay, I removed the onload from my body tag and replaced the old code with the new but it still isn't getting past that page is being loaded picture.

Answer (score 0):

Likely that it's being animated long before your `show()` is invoked. So by the time it's displayed, the animation is done.